Adaptations for Anthropophagy
Let's say there are quadrupedal mammals close to around 100kg that have adapted to live in a typical medieval city and feed on predominantly human beings. The city and the animals therein have existed in stasis for long enough for significant evolution to occur
What adaptations would such animals have, compared to those that eat fish, insects, or nonhuman beasts?

@AlexP -- This is really more of an answer than a comment! Would make for a good frame challenge.

@elemtilas: OK.

build my barely described organism from scratch way too open-ened for this site. they could be pack hunting canines, river ambush crocodiles, venomous ect ect.

(a) I find it unbelievable that a parasitic relationship like this would exist for longer than 1-2 years, much less evolutionary time spans (hundreds of thousands to millions of years). Humans are the apex predator and such a nuisance would be destroyed quickly. If they couldn't destroy the creature, they'd move and continue to move until they find a spot the creature won't live in. (b) Open-ended questions are prohibited (you've been told this over and over).


A "typical medieval city" was really really small and it was filled with humans; there was simply no place for a population of large wild animals. There were no large parks, there were no spacious sewers, no place where those animals could live.
For example, medieval London was the largest city in western Europe. It occupied the territory which is nowadays called the City of London; tens of thousands of people were crammed in that square mile.

There is only one medieval city in Europe where moderately large wild animals, say about dog size, might have had a chance to establish a breeding population, at a specific point in time, and that is Constantinople.
For most of the Middle Ages, up to the 12th century, the area of land surrounded by the Theodosian Walls of Constantinople had contained about half a million people; but, thanks mostly to the devastation of the Fourth Crusade¹, by the late 14th century the population had dropped to some 50,000 people or thereabouts, and there were vast tracts of empty land within the walls.
¹) Yes, the civilized Christian crusaders of western Europe conquered both Jerusalem (First Crusade, 1099) and Constantinople (Fourth Crusade, 1204). In both cases, the victorious conquerers were expelled after less than a hundred years.

We humans are the undisputed top apex predators in this world. We are not prey. The normal and expected response of a human population, any human population, when confronted with large man-eating beasts is to exterminate them. Hunt them, trap them, poison them, whatever. We have an unparalleled track record when it comes to exterminating dangeous large animals.
Which means that quite obviously, the main adaptation of those man-eating beasts would be a magic ability to induce sheepish terminal stupidity in humans.

For example, humans exterminated all the wolves and bears from the entire island of Great Britain. The last bear was killed at some point in the 5th or 6th century, and the last wolf was killed in 1680.
In the Antiquity there were still lions in Greece, in Thrace, and in Macedonia; but they did not make it to the Middle Ages, with the last European lions being killed in the 3rd or the 4th century of the common era.



The Apex Predator of Human is Human
The only apex predator that could in any way blend in and hide in an urban environment and feed on humans is... a human anthropophage. Maybe it's a cult of man-eaters that abduct and kill their prey, then consume them?
